# Static classes, methods, and fields in GWT client

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, static

A colleague who coded the client side of a GWT application has essentially made all widgets and their methods and fields `static`. I am trying to evaluate it's impact.
Based on my reading so far, this has the result of making the javascript objects global for each user's compiled `nocache.js` file. In terms of drawbacks, this is potentially inefficient in that objects are not created dynamically and freed on demand. Also, it's a major hassle to maintain this code.
Are there any other risks in coding the client this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You cannot use your widget in two places in your app: they will keep the last entered data in the lastly used form.
- This must be time consuming at startup (page load), since all widgets of the app are created : there is no control on the instant the widget is created

The recommended way is to have a ClientFactory (http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html#ClientFactory) :
Widget lifetime is controlled through this object that decides whether to create a new instance for each widget request or use the same one

Comment: ClientFactory is recommended since Widget creation is time/resource consuming